# How should I call an overloaded operator in a base abstract class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

So I have a `Base` class:

```
class Base
{
public:
    std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream & out, const Base & base);
}
```

And I have defined what the operator should do:

```
ostream& operator << (std::ostream & out, const Base & base)
{
    return out << "output";
}
```

If I have a `Derived` class that extends `Base` and I want `Derived` to do the same thing as `Base` when its insertion operator is called, what is the best way to go about doing this? And by best I mean best way to not reuse code.

Comment: Have you tried `virtual` methods, wherein overriding is only done if `Derived` behaves differently than `Base`?

Comment: Your operator declaration is invalid.

Comment: Won't this happen anyway, considering you're passing the `Base` by reference (so it could be a `Derived` and still work with the virtual stuff)...once you get it out of the class, anyway?  (A `<<` operator in the class would let you say `aBase << stuff;`, but would have nothing to do with ostreams.)

Comment: @Xeo The definition is poorly-styled, too. Returning the `ostream&` except in the form of `return out;` is just asking for bugs.

Comment: @Xeo Maybe that would explain all the weird errors I'm getting.  What is wrong with it?

Comment: @moshbear I have thought about it, but I am confused about one thing: do I have to declare it in my derived class? Also, I have it defined like that just for the sake of keep this question simple.

Comment: @moshbear: I'd think it'd only act up if people return something besides a stream reference from whatever insertion operators they define...in which case, `os << someCustomObject << "\noops!\n";` would break as well, so nobody in their right mind would do it...

Comment: It'd be best if you read the [FAQ on operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

Comment: @AustinMoore Not unless it touches private variables. Also, `ostream& operator << (ostream&, const Base&)` needs to be defined at namespace-scope, that is, *outside* of the class definition.

Comment: @moshbear Alright, thank you for clarifying.  I read in the link that Xeo provide that "you need to implement these operators for your own types as non-member functions" but that leaves me with a question. Does this mean that insertion operators can't be friends of a class?

Comment: @AustinMoore You have to use forward declarations. Example: http://pastebin.com/4PPf3i3D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a base-class method within a derived class, qualify the call:

```
void Derived::func()
{
   //whatever else you want to do first
   return Base::func();
}
```

Unless the method is `private` you have access to it, since `Derived` is a `Base`.